How do I call an executable as root without the need of using sudo?
I've created an app that also uses TPM for signing/encryption/decryption (with the tss2-fapi library)... But I am a newbie when it comes to Linux (Ubuntu) permissions. Now, when I am running the app I always have to run it as:
sudo ./tpmProjectApp

Running the app like this does not create any problems.
I want any logged in user (also with limited permissions) to run this executable, but I don't want them to communicate with the TPM in any other way.
So I was wondering, is there any way for a user to be able to run this application without needing to use sudo?
I have tried assigning the executable to root with:
sudo chown root ./tpmProjectApp

and setting the setuid bit (I also tried g+s):
sudo chmod u+s tpmProjectApp

The permissions then looked like this:
-rwsrwsrwx 1 root root 713608 apr 14 16:02 tpmProjectApp*

but when I run ./tpmProjectApp I get errors that I normally don't.
e.g.:
Key P_RSA2048SHA256/HS/SRK/myRsaKey not found.
But I know that the key exists, because the app works if I run it with sudo.
I think that assigning root permissions to this executable could be less painful than trying to modify TPM files, in case the problem is there.

Oh dear. Never setuid root something modifiable by everyone on the system. You're basically granting root access to everyone this way. What if I changed your app to an executable that does destructive / nasty things as root?

Yeah I get it. But would user still be able to modify the executable if he wouldn't have write permossion?

Well no, but the permissions show they could...

add entry to /etc/sudoers

What do you mean by that? In read something about not having to use password but still use sudo command.


but when I run ./tpmProjectApp I get errors that I normally don't.
e.g.: Key P_RSA2048SHA256/HS/SRK/myRsaKey not found.
But I know that the key exists, because the app works if I run it with
sudo.

It's probably a little late, but it looks like you should use absolute paths in the script. Example:
/home/fancyusername/P_RSA2048SHA256/HS/SRK/myRsaKey
If you need a relative path to the location of the script, then something like this may work:
$(dirname $(realpath "$0"))/P_RSA2048SHA256/HS/SRK/myRsaKey

How do you know that the file OP is executing is a script?

@stumblebee The OP already answered his own question - he added a setuid bit to the executable, so he does run it as root without using sudo. The original question is answered by OP himself. There is, however, a different problem mentioned in the question - that the application, when running as root, doesn't find the specified file. This answer is trying to address that problem.

@raj I appreciate you pointing that out.

And, if they're running a script, those paths should better be quoted: "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"/P_RSA2048SHA256/HS/SRK/myRsaKey

I had to implement a little workaround for this, but now I tried your solution and it worked as well. Thanks!
